# Force new window to open to the left or right

Tags: buffers, window-splitting, occur

I have two frames open with the following window splits:

```
Frame 1   Frame 2
|---+---+ |------|
|a  |b  | |d     |
|   |   | |      |
|---+---+ |      |
|c      | |      |
|---+---+ |------|
```

Say that I am in window `"a"` or `"b"`.  Sometimes when I call a function that needs a window, a new, tiny one `"e"` will be created instead of using a current one.  This new window is often too small to be of use.

```
Frame 1   Frame 2
|---+---+ |------|
|a  |b  | |d     |
|   |   | |      |
|---+---+ |      |
|c  |e  | |      |
|---+---+ |------|
```

**How could I open new windows in one of the currently existing vertical windows, `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"d"`?**

I have experienced this issue with at least `occur` and `xref-find-definitions-other-window`.

---

The crux of the issue seems to be with the `display-buffer` function.  At first glance it seemed like I could use `display-buffer-in-side-window` to get the behavior I want.  In the case of `occur`, I came up with

```
(setq
 display-buffer-alist
 `(("\\*Occur\\*"
    display-buffer-in-side-window
    (side . right)
    (slot . 0)
    (window-width . fit-window-to-buffer))))
```

This has two problems.

First, it turns out that a side window isn't a window like `"b"` is to `"a"`.  Instead, it is a 'hidden' window that can be toggled.  For instance, the above code does the following when in window `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"c"`

```
Frame 1       Frame 2
|---+---+---| |---|
|a  |b  |e  | |d  |
|   |   |   | |   |
|---+---+   | |   |
|c      |   | |   |
|---+---+---| |---|
```

and does the following when in `"d"`

```
Frame 1   Frame 2
|---+---+ |---|---|
|a  |b  | |d  |e  |
|   |   | |   |   |
|---+---+ |   |   |
|c      | |   |   |
|---+---+ |---|---|
```

Unfortunately, Frame 2 lives on a vertically aligned monitor and the windows `"d"` and `"e"` are too narrow to be convenient.  It's the same kind of problem as before!

The second problem is that it relies on an explicit buffer name.  When using `xref-find-definitions-other-window`, the buffer name varies.

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke `windmove-display-up`/`-down`/`-left`/`-right`, `windmove-display-same-window` (<kbd>C-M-S-0</kbd>) or `windmove-display-new-tab` (<kbd>C-M-S-t</kbd>) right before making a new buffer to specify where to put it.

The function `windmove-display-default-keybindings` sets up key bindings for the directional `windmove-display-*` commands. Withouth arguments, it sets <kbd>S-M-<arrow key></kbd> as the key bindings, so that, for instance, <kbd>S-M-right</kbd> followed by <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> tells Emacs to display the next buffer in the window at the right (creating it if necessary). `windmove-display-default-keybindings` can take as argument a list of modifiers that it will use in place of the default ones. For example, `(windmove-display-default-keybindings '(control meta shift))` sets the key bindings to <kbd>C-M-S-<arrow keys></kbd>.

So, say you have evaluated `(windmove-display-default-keybindings '(control meta shift))`, you're in window `a` and you want to use `xref-find-definitions-other-window` (plain `xref-find-definitions` doesn't obey `windmove-*` functions). You can open the buffer with the definition

- in the current window with <kbd>C-M-S-0</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>xref-find-definitions-other-window</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>;
- in window `b` with <kbd>C-M-S-→</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>xref-find-definitions-other-window</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>;
- in window `c` with <kbd>C-M-S-↓</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>xref-find-definitions-other-window</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>;
- in another tab with <kbd>C-M-S-t</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>xref-find-definitions-other-window</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>;

Same for `occur`: <kbd>C-M-S-0</kbd> <kbd>M-s</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> *`REGEXP`* <kbd>RET</kbd>, and so on. `windmove-*` functions also work on clickable text with <kbd>C-M-S-0</kbd> <kbd>mouse-2</kbd> (middle click) etc..

I don't know how to open the buffer in another frame (window `d`).

Comment: At least on Emacs 28, calling `windmove-display-default-keybindings` does not setup the Shift-Meta+, , ,  keybindings for for the `windmove-display-{up,down,...}` functions. These are super-useful but with paredit, transient and org there are many conflits in the usual bindings.